# pyqt passing signals between classes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-2.x

I have seen similar questions but none of them seems to work in order to solve my problem.

Basically, my intention is very simple. I try to pass the signal from my `settingsWindow` class to the `centerWindow`. Therefore, I created a `Qbject` called `brigde` to pass the signal.

In this example, I suppose to get a print "fire" when I press the Ok Button in the `settingsWindow`. But, nothing is happening.

I'm not sure if I defined all my classes properly. Are all the inheritances correct?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings, QCoreApplication, QSize, QRect, Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (qApp, QApplication, QMainWindow, QFormLayout, QPushButton, QTabWidget,QDialog, QWidget, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy)


class mainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        exitAction = QAction('Exit', self)
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)     

        gSettingAction = QAction('Settings', self)
        gSettingAction.triggered.connect(settingsWindow)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.setMovable(False)
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(gSettingAction)

        self.center_window = centerWindow(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.center_window)



class centerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(centerWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

        wb = bridge()
        wb.valueUpdated.connect(self.fire)


    def initUI(self):
        lytLWin = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox1.addLayout(lytLWin)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox1)


    def fire(self):
        print 'fire'




class settingsWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.win_vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.win_vbox.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab_1") 
        t1 = self.tab1_UI()
        self.tab1.setLayout(t1)

        self.win_vbox.addLayout(self.btnbar())
        self.setLayout(self.win_vbox)

        self.wb = bridge()

        self.exec_()



    def tab1_UI(self):
        lytSettings = QFormLayout()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(lytSettings)

        return vbox


    def btnbar(self):
        ok_set_PB = QPushButton('OK')
        ok_set_PB.setObjectName("ok_set_PB_IH")
        ok_set_PB.clicked.connect(self.ok_settings)     
        cancel_set_PB = QPushButton('Cancel')
        cancel_set_PB.setObjectName("cancel_set_PB_IH")

        btn_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        btn_hbox.addStretch()
        btn_hbox.addWidget(ok_set_PB)
        btn_hbox.addWidget(cancel_set_PB)
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(2, 2, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        btn_hbox.addItem(spacerItem)

        return btn_hbox


    def ok_settings(self):
        self.wb.sendSignal()




class bridge(QObject):
    valueUpdated = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)


    def sendSignal(self):
        self.valueUpdated.emit()



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainWindow()
    ex.setGeometry(100,100,1000,600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Minimal, running examples are much easier to debug, for us and for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are working with different instances, so that it works you should change to the following:

```
class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.wb = bridge()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        [...]
        gSettingAction.triggered.connect(lambda: settingsWindow(self.wb))
        [...]
        self.center_window = centerWindow(self.wb, self)
        [...]

class centerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bridge, parent=None):
        super(centerWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        wb = bridge
        wb.valueUpdated.connect(self.fire)
        [...]

class settingsWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, bridge, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        [...]
        self.wb = bridge
        [...]
```